# Can't set yamler to Psych on Rails 3.2 with Ruby 1.9.2

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-1.9.2, psych

I read in Rails 3 with Ruby 1.9.2 Psych is the default yaml parser. Not for me. It's still syck. Doing

```
require 'yaml'
YAML::ENGINE.yamler = 'psych'
```

as described in various places doesn't work. The yamler is still syck. So it seems to be reset somewhere.

How to set the yamler to Psych?

Answer (score 0):

Since Psych is really just a wrapper around libyaml, you need to make sure you have libyaml installed before compiling and installing Ruby. If you use tool to manage your ruby installation (rvm, rbenv/ruby-build, etc.), they will install this dependency for you automatically.

Comment: I'm using rvm so this can't be the issue